# Joomla component install howto

Tags: joomla

I just had a fresh install of Joomla 1.5 and am trying to install a component.
In extension manager, I choose the zip file of the componenent.

However, I keep on getting this error

- JFolder::create: Could not create directory
- Component Install: Failed to create directory.: "/Users/bhappy/localhost/experiments/site/htdocs/administrator/components/com_portfolio"

What caused those error? I had the chmod for the components and tmp directory set to 777 but still having the same issue.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably a dumb question...

But did you check the permissions on joomla/**administrator**/components? (as opposed to just joomla/components )